# DBVisualizer is only showing Schemas, but not showing tables, and not letting me see data

Tags: mssql-jdbc, dbvisualizer

For some reason, when I started DBVisualizer this time, it stopped showing me tables and data.

It only shows me Schemas.

I have checked using the host's online portal and the tables/data is all still there.

Any ideas why DBVis stopped letting me access it?

[image: DB Visualizer Schema]

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the Schemas node to see more object types such as tables. If there is a problem open a support ticket using **Help->Contact Support** in DbVisualizer.

Comment: I opened the schema tab and there is no Tables

Comment: Open a support ticket in DbVisualizer under Help->Contact Support.